# Is it possible to run ionic app in phonegap build?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

I am working over a project in phonegap. I liked interface and UI tools used in ionic framework and also because of angular.js support. I am curious to know that is it possible to create ionic project and then upload it on ponegap build.

Comment: Yes. I am a volunteer on the *Phonegap Build* forum. We get quite a few people on the forum. However, we often turn them back to the Ionic forum for help - because the most common issues are with the UI, and not the *build*. -- However, one caveat - *Phonegap Build* only requires two (2) files index.html and config.xml, and the must both be in the root directory. Ionic uses a different structure because it uses CLI instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

I've posted about this on the Ionic forums before as there are clear instructions for it.

The way to do it is a bit annoying - you just set up your directory structure in the way you would in PhoneGap Build, but use the Ionic files. Remember to make sure the right files (especially config.xml) is in the right place.

And good luck

**UPDATE:** For *Phonegap Build*, both `index.html` and `config.xml` must be in the root directory. There is no `www/` directory. *For Phonegap CLI*, `config.xml` must be in the root directory and `index.html` must be in `www/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is..
Just download phonegap for your interaction (iOS / android/ other)